# Where can I find a dataset containing legal documents?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, legal

I have a machine learning task I wish to pursue. For the task I will need several hundred sample legal documents of the following types: Employment contract, service contract, sale contract, rental contract/lease, loan contract, confidentiality contract, company formation agreements. I don't expect anyone will have an answer which will help me find all of these contracts but if anyone has any kind of lead as to where I can find a mass amount of one of these contracts it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CFPB Credit Card Agreements DB](http://www.consumerfinance.gov/credit-cards/agreements/) I think that is a service contract.

[docracy - open source legal contracts](http://www.docracy.com/) Requires sign up

Answer (score 3):

This dataset contains labeled and unlabeled legal contracts for contract element extraction. The labeled dataset POS tags as well as annotations for different contract elements. You can refer to the Read me section for more details.

http://nlp.cs.aueb.gr/software_and_datasets/CONTRACTS_ICAIL2017/index.html

Answer (score 1):

CUAD: An Expert-Annotated NLP Dataset for Legal Contract Review - https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06268

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles onto this question during my research I also found this site: https://www.scribd.com/ This has millions of documents of all kinds available to download.

Comment: How is this a good dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all SEC filings that public companies make on the SEC's website: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Here's a scraper that'll grab different types of SEC filings in bulk from the SEC website: https://github.com/javedqadruddin/EDGAR

Answer (score 0):

[Legal Case Reports Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Legal+Case+Reports#)

Data Set Information:

This dataset contains Australian legal cases from the Federal Court of Australia (FCA). The cases were downloaded from AustLII ([Web Link]). We included all cases from the year 2006,2007,2008 and 2009. We built it to experiment with automatic summarization and citation analysis. For each document we collected catchphrases, citations sentences, citation catchphrases, and citation classes. Catchphrases are found in the document, we used the catchphrases are gold standard for our summarization experiments. Citation sentences are found in later cases that cite the present case, we use citation sentences for summarization. Citation catchphrases are the catchphrases (where available) of both later cases that cite the present case, and older cases cited by the present case. Citation classes are indicated in the document, and indicate the type of treatment given to the cases cited by the present case.

Comment: I've used this dataset before. It is a corpus of legal cases, but not specifically contract law.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SEC EDGAR Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sec-edgar-viewer/9p8l8snm3kgx?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

You get all SEC Filings in real-time. Analyze and download filing documents.

Comment: For a free service in Python https://github.com/edgarminers/python-edgar (not mine).